# C# Click inside iframe

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Well i need a help for detecting a iframe in webpage (c# form) and simulate a click inside anywhere in the iframe.
I tried this code to get iframe with the id inside the iframe but no idea to completete it fully.

```
var frame = webBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames["iframeid"];
```

I looked at many topics and i couldn't preciously get a exact ouput i want maybe also because iam new newbie in this thing so please guys help and it would be great appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to switch to iframe and then you can perform operations.

Try (C#):

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(string frameName); // Select a frame by its name or ID.
```

Or

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(int frameIndex); // Select a frame by its (zero-based) index.
```

Or

```
IWebDriver Frame(IWebElement frameElement); //Select a frame using its previously located OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement
```